# Is it possible to create my own custom SQL 'trigger' with Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm familiar with MSSQL triggers already, however they aren't fine grained enough for what I want to do. In my scenario I want the trigger to fire after a row containing certain information lands in the table; not every time an UPDATE is performed.

I've used Powershell scripts to 'listen' for files dropping in a certain location, and then sending an email, I'm just wondering if this is at all possible with MS SQL server?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking about how to do this with powershell, or are you asking about [sql triggers with where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173119/sql-server-triggers-on-specific-data)?

Comment: That may well be what I'm after... I'll check it out, thanks